# compute angle between two rasters

Tags: r, angle, raster

My question is how to compute the angle between two rasters in R? 
Here is a reproductible example and the error I get:

```
angle <-function(vectora, vectorb){
      theta <- acos( sum(vectora*vectorb) / ( sqrt(sum(vectora * vectora)) * sqrt(sum(vectorb * vectorb)) )) 
}

raster1 <- raster(ncols=150, nrows=150, xmn=0)
raster1[] <-  rnorm(150*150,ncell(1))
raster2 <- raster(ncols=150, nrows=150, xmn=0)
raster2[] <-  rnorm(150*150,ncell(2))

r.angle <- overlay(raster1,raster2, filename='tes.tif',fun=function(x,y){angle(x,y)})
```

The error message is the following:

```
Error in (function (x, fun, filename = "", recycle = TRUE, ...)  : 
  cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized
```

How can I get that vectorized?

Comment: Maybe, if you add a `return(theta)` statement in your function and, apply the `angle` function as `r.angle <- overlay(raster1, raster2, filename='tes.tif', fun = function(x,y) { mapply(angle, x[], y[]) })`? Also, in my computer I had to change filename to `tes.tiff` to view the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment, changing two things will fix the problem. The vectorization comes in through raster1[] and raster2[], so you need to modify the application of the function.

```
function(x,y){angle(x[],y[])})
```

and add a return at the end of the function angle():

```
return(theta)
```